# Possible to provide a URL as an OpenGraph object in Facebook SDK 4 for Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am aware that ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder() in SDK4 allows you to build an Open Graph object by hard coding the values using .putString("og:type", "books.book") etc...

But before the SDK 4 update I could provide a URL that represented my object straight into OpenGraphAction.setType() and then publish the story using OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder. This does not seem to be the case anymore.

Is there a way to dynamically build an Open Graph story using a URL as an Open Graph Object in Facebook SDK 4 for Android?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `putString()` method on the `ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()`:

```
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
        .setActionType("books.reads")
        .putString("book", "http://www.myserver.com/my_object_page")
        .build();
ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
        .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
        .setAction(action)
        .build();
ShareDialog.show(this, content);
```